# tar -C fails in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to decompress a tar file with this code in my chef recipe :

```
execute "#{node['ffmpeg']['yasm']}.tar.gz" do
      command "tar -xzvf /tmp/#{node['ffmpeg']['yasm']}.tar.gz -C #{node['ffmpeg']['source_files']}"
```

But the next command fails saying that there's no such file in the specified directory. What's going on? What do I do? The file and the directory exist
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might have struggled like me, the solution I arrived at was

```
bash "extract-yasm" do
  cwd path/to/destination
  code <<-EOH
  tar -xzvf /tmp/file-name.tar.gz
  EOH
end
```

Thanks everyone for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that `/tmp/#{node['ffmpeg']['yasm']}.tar.gz` exists and change directory `-C` also exists.

Before `execute` you can put:

```
   directory node['ffmpeg']['source_files'] do
     recursive true
   end
```

in order to create change dir if its missing.

In order to check if file exists `/tmp/#{node['ffmpeg']['yasm']}.tar.gz` you can add

```
  only_if { ::File.exist?("/tmp/#{node['ffmpeg']['yasm']}.tar.gz") }
```

to your execute resource.

In that case your code will be protected by the errors.

One more thing - if you need to create `change directory` only if `execute` resource is triggered you need to use `notify resource`.

Comment: The file and the directory exist. This is something I have seen before in Chef. It tends to decompress in it's working directory instead of the specified directory. But my memory of that incident is hazy so I was wondering if you could point out what's up with that - where that working directory and how that could be overcome